Integral of $\int \left(1 + \cot\left(x - {\alpha}\right) \cot\left(x + {\alpha}\right)\right) \mathrm{d}x$
$$\int \left(1 + \cot\left(x - {\alpha}\right) \cot\left(x + {\alpha}\right)\right) \mathrm{d}x$$
To solve this I simplified it as follows:
$$\int \left(1 + \frac{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 \alpha}{\sin^2 x - \sin^2 \alpha}\right) \, dx$$
And I cannot proceed further. Pls help me solve this integral.

Several cases have to be distinguished based on the value of the parameter $\alpha$.
When $\alpha \notin \frac{\pi}{2}\Bbb{Z}$.
Hermite's identity is the most straightforward simplification when $\alpha$ is not a multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$. It states that
$$
\cot(x-\alpha)\cot(x+\alpha) = -1 + \cot(2\alpha)\cot(x-\alpha) - \cot(2\alpha)\cot(x+\alpha),
$$
hence, given that $\ln|\sin x|$ is a primitive of $\cot x$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int 1+\cot(x-\alpha)\cot(x+\alpha) \,\mathrm{d}x
   &= \cot(2\alpha) \int \cot(x-\alpha) - \cot(x+\alpha) \,\mathrm{d}x \\
   &= \cot(2\alpha)\ln\left|\frac{\sin(x-\alpha)}{\sin{(x+\alpha)}}\right| + C
\end{align}
$$
where $C$ is the arbitrary constant of integration.
When $\alpha \in \pi\Bbb{Z}$.
Given that cotangent is an odd $\pi$-periodic function, one has $\cot(x-\alpha)\cot(x+\alpha) = \cot^2x$ in that case. Since $\cot' = -1-\cot^2$, one deduces directly that
$$
\int 1+\cot(x-\alpha)\cot(x+\alpha) \,\mathrm{d}x
   = \int 1+\cot^2x \,\mathrm{d}x 
   = -\cot x + C
$$
When $\alpha \in \pi\left(\Bbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$.
In the same spirit as previously, given that cotangent is an odd $\pi$-periodic function with $\cot(x-\frac{\pi}{2}) = -\tan x$, one has $\cot(x-\alpha)\cot(x+\alpha) = \tan^2x$ in that last case. Since $tan' = 1+\tan^2$, one deduces straightforwardly that
$$
\int 1+\cot(x-\alpha)\cot(x+\alpha) \,\mathrm{d}x
   = \int 1+\tan^2x \,\mathrm{d}x 
   = \tan x + C
$$
Conclusion.
In short, one has :
$$
\int 1+\cot(x-\alpha)\cot(x+\alpha) \,\mathrm{d}x = 
\begin{cases}
    \tan x + C & \text{if } \alpha = \pm\frac{\pi}{2}, \pm\frac{3\pi}{2}, \ldots \\
   -\cot x + C & \text{if } \alpha = \pm\pi, \pm2\pi, \ldots \\
   \cot(2\alpha)\ln\left|\frac{\sin(x-\alpha)}{\sin{(x+\alpha)}}\right| + C & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

There is a standard trigonometric identity
$$\cot(\theta-\phi)=\dfrac{1+\cot{\theta}\cot{\phi}}{\cot{\phi}-\cot{\theta}}$$
so that
$$1+\cot{\theta}\cot{\phi}=(\cot{\phi}-\cot{\theta})\cot(\theta-\phi).$$
So here
$$1+\cot{(x-\alpha)}\cot{(x+\alpha)}=(\cot{(x+\alpha)}-\cot{(x-\alpha)})\cot(-2\alpha)
=(\cot{(x-\alpha)}-\cot{(x+\alpha}))\cot(2\alpha)$$
Hence the integral
$$
=\cot(2\alpha)\int(\cot{(x-\alpha)}\cot{(x+\alpha)})dx
=\cot(2\alpha)(\ln{\sin{|x-\alpha|}}-\ln{\sin|x+\alpha|})+c$$

What if $\alpha = \pi$ for instance ?

Good point. I see other posts have dealt with the various special cases.

$$I= \int \cot\left(x - 1\right) \cot\left(x + a\right) \, \mathrm{d}x + \int  \, \mathrm{d}x$$
$\int dx$ is just $x+C_1$
Under $u=x-a$ we get
$$\int \cot\left(x - a\right) \cot\left(x + a\right) \, \mathrm{d}x = \int \cot\left(u\right) \cot\left(u + 2a\right) \, \mathrm{d}u= \int \frac{\cot\left(u\right) \left(\cot\left(2a\right) \cot\left(u\right) - 1\right)}{\cot\left(u\right) + \cot\left(2a\right)} \, \mathrm{d}u$$
Substitute $v = \cot\left(u\right)$ and we get
$$= -\int \frac{v \left(\cot\left(2a\right) \, v - 1\right)}{\left(v + \cot\left(2a\right)\right) \left(v^{2} + 1\right)} \, \mathrm{d}v=-\left[ \cot\left(2a\right) \int \frac{1}{v + \cot\left(2a\right)} \, \mathrm{d}v - \int \frac{1}{v^{2} + 1} \, \mathrm{d}v\right
]=-(I_1-I_2)$$
For $I_1$
$$\int \frac{1}{v + \cot\left(2a\right)} \, \mathrm{d}v= \log\left(v + \cot\left(2a\right)\right)+C_2$$
For $I_2$
$$\int \frac{1}{v^{2} + 1} \, \mathrm{d}v= \arctan\left(v\right)+C_3$$
Plugging those in to the original integral we get
$$\int \left(\cot\left(x - a\right) \cot\left(x + a\right) + 1\right) \mathrm{d}x= -\cot\left(2a\right) \log\left(\left|\cot\left(x - a\right) + \cot\left(2a\right)\right|\right) + \arctan\left(\cot\left(x - a\right)\right) + x + C$$

What if $\alpha = \pi$ for instance ?

\begin{align*}
I&=\int1+\cot(x-\alpha)\cot(x+\alpha)\,dx \\
&=\int1+\frac{\cos(x-\alpha)\cos(x+\alpha)}{\sin(x-\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)}\,dx \\
&=\int\frac{\sin(x-\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)+\cos(x-\alpha)\cos(x+\alpha)}{\sin(x-\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)}\,dx \\
&=\int\frac{\cos(x+\alpha-(x-\alpha))}{\sin(x-\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)}\,dx \\
&=\int\frac{\cos(2\alpha)}{\sin(x-\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)}\,dx \\
&=\int\frac{\cot(2\alpha)\sin(2\alpha)}{\sin(x-\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)}\,dx \\
&=\int\frac{\cot(2\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha-(x-\alpha))}{\sin(x-\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)}\,dx \\
&=\int\frac{\cot(2\alpha)(\sin(x+\alpha)\cos(x-\alpha)-\cos(x+\alpha)\sin(x-\alpha))}{\sin(x-\alpha)\sin(x+\alpha)}\,dx \\
&=\int\cot(2\alpha)(\cot(x-\alpha)-\cot(x+\alpha))\,dx \\
&=\cot(2\alpha)(\ln|\sin(x-\alpha)|-\ln|\sin(x+\alpha)|+c\\
\end{align*}

What if $\alpha = \pi$ for instance ?
